# What is equivalent method of ALAsssetsLibrary’s assetForURL:resultBlock:failure in Photos Framework?

Tags: ios, ios9, photosframework, assetslibrary

I am picking image using `UIImagePickerController` but I also need image’s name and other metadata information. I could have fetched image asset using `ALAsssetsLibrary’s` `assetForURL:resultBlock:failure` method with the help of referenceURL provided by `UIImagePickerController` after picking image but that method/Framework is deprecated in iOS9. I searched for its equivalent method in `Photos Framework` but I didn’t find one.

Let me know its equivalent method or any other way to fetch selected image’s metadata using `Photos Framework`.

Comment: Use `+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions *)options` from `Photos.framework`

Comment: @CuteAngel thanks, it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can read metada with Photos Framework like that;

```
asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(options) { (fooContentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput!, _) -> Void in
    //Get full image
    let imageUrl = fooContentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL
    let orientation = fooContentEditingInput.fullSizeImageOrientation
    var finalImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
    finalImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingOrientation(orientation)

    for (key, value) in finalImage.properties() {
        println("key: \(key)")
        println("value: \(value)")
    }
}
```